# how to set htm with span tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, methods, html

This piece of code is working fine:

```
$("#myp").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
```

i.e. it displays in myp world in bold

but adding span style color like this:

```
$("#myp").html("<span style="color: #F00;">Hello </span><b>world!</b>");
```

is not working anymore, it does not display anything in the web page

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your console btw

Comment: The syntax coloring gives it away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes inside your string:

```
$("#myp").html("<span style=\"color: #F00;\">Hello </span><b>world!</b>");
```

Or use a different string delimiter:

```
$("#myp").html('<span style="color: #F00;">Hello </span><b>world!</b>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape double quote inside string:

```
$("#myp").html("<span style=\"color: #F00;\">Hello </span><b>world!</b>");
```

Or use single ones:

```
$("#myp").html("<span style='color: #F00;'>Hello </span><b>world!</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes while adding style

```
            $("#myp").html("<span style='color: #F00;'>Hello </span><b>world!</b>");
```

or escape double quotes used inside while adding style

```
             $("#myp").html("<span style=\"color: #F00;\">Hello </span><b>world!</b>");
```